# iOS Accessing dates from images in the bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, date, nsdate, resourcebundle

My app is an image loader that copies images from the bundle to the camera roll. Unfortunately the only date I can get from the images is NOW. I have tried copying the images to my app as well as using references. Both result in the same date which is NOW.

Currently I am using:

```
NSMutableDictionary *EXIFDictionary = [[metadataAsMutable objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]mutableCopy];

[EXIFDictionary setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal];

NSLog(@"Date %@", [EXIFDictionary valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal]);
```

Is there any way to get the actual asset creation date from an asset in the bundle?

Thanks in advance,

Joe